# Relative path in fstream open() Mac OS X does not work

Tags: c++, macos, file, fstream, ofstream

Does fstream's open() take relative or absolute file paths? Here is the example code  -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    fstream myfile;

    myfile.open("subd/example.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    myfile << "Example data " << i << endl;
            }
    } else cout << "Unable to open " << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I working on a MAC OS X environment. The subdirectory already exists. .open() returns false for each of these cases. I am also using -std=c++11. How do I get around this problem?
The permissions for the 'subd' directory are :

[image]

The output is always "Unable to open". **The solution of the original post(the one this post is marked the duplicate of) does not solve my problem.**

> **Solution, because none of the responses below completely resolve my issue**
>
> Use ofstream with the relative path(with respect to the location of
>   the program executable ie. argv[0]). fstream just doesn't seem to work
>   the same way.

Comment: It takes whatever path you give it. A path that starts with "/" is absolute, all other paths are relative (to the current working directory).

Comment: Example 2 is bogus. It's "subdirectory/example.txt".

The others should work. You either lack +r permission on one of the involved directories or you simply made a typo.

Comment: I have added a more clear example. Do other users need write access as well ?

Comment: Are you executing this from the directory that has "subd" as a subdirectory?

Comment: print out the current working directory. you're not running from the folder you think you are

Comment: Why doesn't it work when I put in the absolute path? (from the root to the subdirectory). I mean why do have to know the calling environment's working directory?

Answer (score 0):

> Does fstream's open() take relative or absolute file paths?

**Yes.**

And if relative then it's relative to the calling environment's *[current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)*.

Note that this may not be your source code's location on disk.

Comment: It does not work when I put in the absolute path. (from the root to the subdirectory). I mean why do have to know the calling environment's working directory? And if the current working directory is associated with argv[0], then that doesn't work in my case too. Like "./subd/example.txt"

Comment: @KartikYadav: `subd/example.txt` This is not an absolute path.

Comment: I know. But something like this "/home/kartik/Downloads/P4/subd/example.txt" or "~/Downloads/P4/subd/example.txt" does not work as well. The value of is_open() is still false.

Comment: @KartikYadav: Then your program does not have permission to read that file.

Comment: The file (ie example.txt) does not exist. I expect open() to make one. The directory (ie. subd) does exist and has the permissions I mentioned in the post above which allows rwx for owner and group whereas rx for others. I did add w to others as well, but that didn't work either.